# Line ending conversion program

Tags: code-golf, conversion, file-system, whitespace

Write a program or function that alters the file at a user-specified filename via replacing all instances of UNIX line endings with Windows line endings and vice versa.

Clarifications:

- For the purposes of this problem, a UNIX line ending consists of the octet `0A` in hexadecimal, except when it is immediately preceded by the octet `0D`. A Windows line ending consists of the two octets `0D 0A`.
- As usual, your program only has to run on one (pre-existing) interpreter on one (pre-existing) operating system; this is particularly important for this question, where I imagine many submissions will succeed on UNIX but fail on Windows, or vice versa, due to line ending conversions built into the language.
- To alter a file, you can either edit the file "in-place", or read the file, then save the contents of the file back over the original. However, the program must alter a file on disk; just taking a string as an argument and returning a string specifying the result is not acceptable for this challenge, because the challenge is partially about testing the ability to handle files.
- The program's user must have some method of specifying the filename to change without needing to alter the program itself (i.e. you can't use hardcoded filenames). For example, you could read the name of the file to modify from a command-line argument, or from standard input. If you're submitting a function rather than a full program, making it take a filename as argument would be acceptable.
- The input to the program must be specified as a *filename* specifically; you can't take input other than strings (assuming that you're using an operating system in which filenames are strings; in most, they are), and you can't place restrictions on what filenames you accept (you must accept all filenames that the operating system would accept, and that refer to a file that the user running the program has permission to read and write). For example, you can't write a function that takes a UNIX file descriptor as an argument and requires the file to already be open, and you can't write an editor macro that assumes the file has already been opened in the current buffer.
- If the file is missing a trailing newline before you alter it, it should continue to be missing a trailing newline after you alter it. Likewise, if the file does have a trailing newline, you should preserve that (leaving the file with the other sort of trailing newline).
- If the input file has mixed line ending conventions, you should nonetheless translate each of the line endings to the opposite sort of line ending (so the resulting line will still have mixed line ending conventions, but each individual line will have been converted).
- The program is intended for use converting text files, and as such, you don't have to be able to handle *nonprintable* control codes in the input (although you can if you wish). The nonprintable control codes are the octets from `00` to `1F` (hexadecimal) inclusive except for `09`, `0A`, `0B`, `0C`, `0D`. It's also acceptable for your program to fail on input that cannot be decoded as UTF-8 (however, there is no requirement to place a UTF-8 interpretation on the input; programs which handle all the high-bit-set octets are also acceptable).
- As an exception from the specification, it's acceptable for the program to do anything upon seeing the octet sequence `0D 0D 0A` in the input (because it's impossible to comply with the spec when this sequence appears in the input: you'd have to generate `0D` followed by an `0A` which is not immediately preceded by `0D`, which is a contradiction).

The shortest program wins, under usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules (i.e. fewest bytes in the program you submit). Good luck!

### Test cases

Here are some hex dumps of files you can use to test your program. All these test cases are *reversible*; swapping the input and output gives another valid test case. Note that your program should work for cases other than the given test-cases; these are just some examples to help testing:

---

**Input**

```
30 31 32 0A 33 34 35 0A 36 37 38 0A
```

**Output**

```
30 31 32 0D 0A 33 34 35 0D 0A 36 37 38 0D 0A
```

---

**Input**

```
30 31 0A 0D 0A 32 0A 0A 0A 33 34
```

**Output**

```
30 31 0D 0A 0A 32 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 33 34
```

---

**Input** and **Output** both a zero-byte file.

Comment: Could you give some examples? Like normal and edge cases?

Comment: Sure, I've added a few. Note that there's not much variety possible; the actual algorithmic part of the challenge is fairly simple.

Comment: the input/output **has** to be files? or could be string (representing the content)?

Comment: @Rod: **has** to be files. That's already stated in the question: "However, the program must alter a file on disk; just taking a string as an argument and returning a string specifying the result is not acceptable for this challenge, because the challenge is partially about testing the ability to handle files."

Comment: So just for understanding your second example in `0A 0D 0A`, the transform is `0A` -> `0D 0A` and `0D 0A` -> `0A` resulting in `0D 0A 0A`?

Comment: @KarlNapf: that's right; the problem's basically about replacing `0D 0A` with `0A` and vice versa.

Comment: -1 for requiring file I/O. [Arbitrarily overriding the defaults](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8065/12012) is one of the things to avoid when writing challenges.

Comment: The override isn't arbitrary. The "read the file, then write it back at the same location" task is a) the way this particular task is normally most useful practically, and b) not actually a method of I/O that's acceptable under default rules. So it's not overriding the defaults any more than "print hello world" is overriding the defaults; it's part of the task, not part of the I/O method (and in fact, it wouldn't be allowed if it were an I/O method!). I didn't override the defaults with respect to the actual input of the challenge (which is the filename).

Comment: Can we assume the file won't include bytes equal to `0` (null) or maybe `4` (end of transmission)? Just in case...

Comment: I don't know what PPCG's standard rules are on assumptions about what the input file can contain, and I'll be shouted at if I answer the question in the comments :-(. This problem's mostly useful in the context of text files, though, which rarely contain characters like that, so I guess I'll edit the question to specify a character repertoire you have to handle.

Comment: That's very reasonable. And helped me save 2 bytes :-D

Comment: The challenge is interesting, I'm ok with IO manipulation and I've dealt with the EOL issue before, but why mixed EOL conventions?

Comment: @adrianmp: basically because this site requires you to define the puzzle explicitly, including cases like that. I'd be surprised if it makes much of a difference in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

## Sed (GNU), <del>27</del>, <del>37</del>, 24 bytes (21 byte + *"-zi"* flags)

(21 byte for code + 3 for "-zi" flags)

EDIT: I've just spotted an issue with an extra carriage return being appended to files with no trailing newline, when going from Unix to DOS.

This is now fixed, and I've also re-profiled my answer to pure *Sed* instead of *Bash*, and added some tests.

**Golfed**

```
s|\n|\r\n|g;s|\r\r||g
```

**Usage**

```
sed -zi -f newline.sed myfile.txt
```

**Tests**

> An old pond!
> A frog jumps in —
> the sound of water.
>
> (Matsuo Basho)

**Test Case #1, Unix newlines + trailing newline**

```
>xxd haiky.txt
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210a 4120  An old pond !.A 
0000010: 6672 6f67 206a 756d 7073 2069 6e20 e280  frog jumps in ..
0000020: 940a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66 2077  ..the sound of w
0000030: 6174 6572 2e0a                           ater.

>sed -zi -f newline.sed haiku.txt 
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210d 0a41  An old pond !..A
0000010: 2066 726f 6720 6a75 6d70 7320 696e 20e2   frog jumps in .
0000020: 8094 0d0a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66  ....the sound of
0000030: 2077 6174 6572 2e0d 0a                    water...

>sed -zi -f newline.sed haiku.txt 
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210a 4120  An old pond !.A 
0000010: 6672 6f67 206a 756d 7073 2069 6e20 e280  frog jumps in ..
0000020: 940a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66 2077  ..the sound of w
0000030: 6174 6572 2e0a                           ater..
```

**Test Case #2, Unix newlines, no trailing newline**

```
>xxd haiku.no-trailing-newline.txt
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210a 4120  An old pond !.A 
0000010: 6672 6f67 206a 756d 7073 2069 6e20 e280  frog jumps in ..
0000020: 940a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66 2077  ..the sound of w
0000030: 6174 6572 2e                             ater.

>sed -zi -f newline.sed haiku.no-trailing-newline.txt
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210d 0a41  An old pond !..A
0000010: 2066 726f 6720 6a75 6d70 7320 696e 20e2   frog jumps in .
0000020: 8094 0d0a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66  ....the sound of
0000030: 2077 6174 6572 2e

>sed -zi -f newline.sed haiku.no-trailing-newline.txt
0000000: 416e 206f 6c64 2070 6f6e 6420 210a 4120  An old pond !.A 
0000010: 6672 6f67 206a 756d 7073 2069 6e20 e280  frog jumps in ..
0000020: 940a 7468 6520 736f 756e 6420 6f66 2077  ..the sound of w
0000030: 6174 6572 2e                             ater.
```

Comment: Both are true. I've correct it to handle conversion in both sides, and added explicit $1. Thank you !

Comment: I think it works now, although you can probably save several bytes via the use of a `;` in the `sed` program rather than using `-e` twice.

Comment: You can combine the `-i` and `-e`, and combine the two sed expression into one with a `;`: `sed -ie "s/$/\r/;s/\r\r$//" $1`

Comment: @Riley, true, actually I did this in the original version (which was shown to have a flaw by @ais523). Will restore that now.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 28 bytes

```
&Z$[13X]OZt5E6MZtO10ZtG3$FZ#
```

This works in [current release (19.5.1)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/19.5.1), which is predates the challenge.

I have only tested it on Windows, but it should work on Linux too.

Because of file input/ouput this can't be tested online directly. But here is an [online version](https://tio.run/##VY6xTsMwFEX3fsXtgARLFPeRUsYIMaJKqAMNYnixX4vBsav4uRJfH1LEAHc6y9U5A2uYpg@Spelai7@7wrOwQ9bRxyM4OtgUzzIqNMGJ9QOHCte7d4GFz0gxfCGKOHHoxXLJgnQAoy9H@Ij5mn2KMPdVU5mbxauhl7dtp83j@qnTrak7vUhbq4XD7HKyMPu23tulkf9dD78do@QSFD3bz0uTziU@norikMaBdZqoBhnQCnULItAtqPnhNegOtJn5Gw) that accepts and produces hex-dump strings with the format shown in the challenge.

#### Explanation

```
&Z$      % Implicitly input filename, and read as chars
[13X]    % Push array [13 10]
O        % Push 0
Zt       % Replace [13 10] by 0
5E       % Push 10
6M       % Push [13 10] again
Zt       % Replace 10 by [13 10]
O        % Push 0
10       % Push 10
Zt       % Replace 0 by 10
G        % Push filename again
3$FZ#    % Overwrite the file with the modified char array
```

Comment: Is MATL the only golf language with file I/O?

Comment: @Razetime I’m pretty sure there are others, but I can’t remember right now

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>240</s> <s>219</s> <s>211</s> 227 bytes

Saving a little by `#define...fputc` and a lot by converting to a program. -8 bytes for converting some logic. +16 bytes for in-place file replacement using the temporary file `T`

Takes filenames via command line parameters.

```c
#import<stdio.h>
#define P(c) fputc(c,o)
d;int main(int c,char**v){FILE*i=fopen(v[1],"r"),*o=fopen("T","w");while((c=fgetc(i))!=-1){if(c==10)P(13),P(c);else if(c==13){if((d=fgetc(i))!=10)P(c);P(d);}else P(c);}rename("T",v[1]);}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
#import<stdio.h>
#define P(c) fputc(c,o)
d;
int main(int c,char**v){
  FILE*i=fopen(v[1],"r"),*o=fopen("T","w");
  while((c=fgetc(i))!=-1){
    if(c==10)
      fputc(13,o),fputc(c,o);
    else if(c==13)
      if((d=fgetc(i))!=10)
        fputc(c,o);
      fputc(d,o);
    else fputc(c,o);
  }
  rename("T",v[1]);
}
```

Usage:

```c
./a.out test_in.txt
```

Comment: This isn't quite complete by itself; it's writing to a new file, rather than overwriting the original. I think you can most easily fix this via using a hardcoded filename for `O` and doing a `rename(O,I)` at the end of the function; there might be a way that requires fewer bytes though.

Comment: @ais523 Ah okay, I misinterpreted your third point. I guess `rename` is fine for this stage of the program, which might not be final.