# Convert all the newlines in a file from \r\n to \n

Tags: code-golf, file-system

Inspired by what I'm doing at work right now.

Your program should take one parameter, the path to the file

It should convert all the windows style newlines (\r\n) to unix style (\n) and write the result back to the file

Comment: Can we assume that the file never contains \r without \n immediately following?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101374/78410).

Comment: As this is a subset of the problem in the question linked by @Bubbler, I’ve voted to close as a duplicate

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate. Too bad search didn't find it

Comment: @Adám yes you can

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>22</s> bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
10@3∘⎕NGET⎕NPUT{⍵1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUVfzo76pfu6uIY96t2qqqxsagLgBoSCuYe3/tEdtEx719oFU9a551Lvl0HrjR20TgUqCg5yBZIiHZ/B/EM9DPTU5I19BN1VBKTEppigmLzklNQ1Ep2fEFCkp2CmUpBaXqHNBlFZUpED5aQrqWCUA)

`⎕NGET` get content,encoding,line-ending from argument file

`10@3∘` replace the third element (line ending) with 10, meaning \n

`⎕NPUT` put that into…

`{⍵1}` the file name followed by an overwrite flag